# Create flow in power automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I want to create a flow in Power Automate to send email whenever a new row is added to any table.
Currently, it is possible to send an email when a new row is added to a specific table, but if we have 100 tables, we have to write 100 flows since in each flow we have specify the table name.
So is it possible to dynamically select table in which a new row is added and send an email.
So, only 1 flow is necessary for 100 tables.
Is this possible?

What i tried : create separate flows for each table

Expectation : Single flow which dynamically identifies table. So only 1 flow for any number of tables

Comment: could you possibly specify what system is used to store the tables you're talking about? i.e. what is the trigger action you use in Power Automate?

Comment: Hi  @teylyn
Thanks for showing interest.
I am using Microsoft Dataverse tables.
I am not sure what trigger action to use to dynamically find tables in which a new row is added. I want help with the whole flow.

Comment: I'm not sure if the data source is making any difference in this context. The trigger cannot be dynamic in this sense, since in the Power Automate studio subsequent actions can reference fields in the schema of the table selected.

Comment: Hi @mmikesy90
Thanks for replying.
So in conclusion, it is not possible to make a single flow in power automate to send email for all the tables ?